# Facebook Share Dialog: Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have page with photos, each having a "Share" link. The event handler for the Share link is:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'http://mydomain.com/path/to/image.jpg',
    display: 'popup'
}, function(response){});
```

It successfully opens the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog), however it says `Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.`

[image]

I close it, and when I click Share again, it displays the full `href` of the item to be shared, without a thumbnail.

[image]

Subsequent clicks render the same (2nd) dialog. When "Post to Facebook" is clicked, it successfully posts: It shows up on Facebook feeds without a thumbnail, but when clicked, as expected, shows the photo.

I used Open Graph Debugger and I get:

[image]

where `Graph API` is:

```
{
    "id": "ID_HERE",
    "created_time": "2014-05-21T02:09:26+0000",
    "is_scraped": true,
    "title": "http://mydomain.com/path/to/image.jpg",
    "type": "website",
    "updated_time": "2014-05-21T02:10:49+0000",
    "url": "http://mydomain.com/path/to/image.jpg"
}
```

and `Scraped URL` displays blank page.

I should mention the following:

- `/path/to/image.jpg` actually calls a PHP script that uses a [PHP thumbnailing library](https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb) to display the photo
- `/path/to/image.jpg` when navigated to by the browser displays the image just fine (`Content-Type:image/jpeg`)
- I have removed Gzip compression in my .htaccess (I am using HTML5 boilerplate) as suggested by other SO question/answers
- Users login through my website using `<fb:login-button scope="email,user_birthday">`

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**EDIT**

Here's the URL of the image: http://race.ph/image/race_photo/view/6.jpg

Comment: What is the URL? For some reason Facebook can't access it and it is hard to help you without knowing what url Facebook have problems with

Comment: @WizKid I added the URL

Comment: any solution here? same behaviour